# Let $u_n$ be the $n$-th entry in the Fibonacci sequence $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,\ldots$

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

If you start with $u_1 = 1$ and $u_2 = 1$, then the sequence can be generated using the formula $$u_{n+1} = u_n + u_{n-1}\ .$$ If $u_n = r^n$, what is r?

Can anyone figure this out? I am so stuck please help!

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number.

Comment: If $u_n = r^n$, then can you compute $u_{n + 1}$ as a power of $r$?

Comment: Well, you have an equation there. If $u_{n} = r^{n}$, then the relation $u_{n+1} = u_{n} + u_{n-1}$ implies $r^{n+1} = r^{n} + r^{n-1}$. Now can you solve for $r$?

Comment: Guys I think the question is "which numbers of the Fibonacci sequence have an integer n-th root, where n is their position in the sequence?"

Comment: @user130520, Make question clear.

Comment: I'm still not really getting it. I tried solving for r, and it makes sense mathematically but really only if I use u_n= u_n-1 + u_n-2 but I need help with this proof.

Comment: If r is integer, then only solution is r=1.

Answer (score 0):

$F_n$ is *approximately* equal to $\dfrac{\Phi^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\Phi$ is the golden ratio, $\Phi = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$.

If $F_{n+2} = F_{n+1} + F_n$ and $F_{n+1} = rF_n$, then $r^2F_n = rF_n + F_n$ and $r^2 = r + 1$ or $r^2 - r - 1 = 0$.  This quadratic has roots $\Phi$ and $1 - \Phi = \dfrac{1 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$ which is negative.

Comment: my problem is where does n+2 come in? and where did we get phi from?

Comment: It's better style to deal with $F_{n+2}, F_{n+1}, $ and $F_n$ than $F_{n+1}, F_n, $ and $ F_{n-1}$.  And $\Phi$ is a root of the quadratic $r^2 - r - 1$, long associated with the Fibonacci sequence.